# Would using useEffect hook in React cause conflciting data for fraction of seconds?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is an example given in the React docs for fetching data with `useEffect`.

```js
export default function Page() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState('Alice');
  const [bio, setBio] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    setBio(null);
    fetchBio(person).then(result => {
      if (!ignore) {
        setBio(result);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [person]);
```

When the state person changes, the component will re-render, with a new person name and then `useEffect` runs and set the state bio with the fetched data.  Now the screen shows a new person's name and bio. But before `useEffect` runs, and as the component re-renders with the new person's name, the screen will have the new person's name but the old person's bio for a short time. Is my understanding correct, if so is there any way to change this behavior

Comment: This is due to the fact that the api is called once person name changes and its showing old bio until the api response is resolved.

Comment: Set the bio's display to none util it loads.

Comment: If you set the `bio` state null when updating the `person` state, then no, there's not really any discrepancy here between the two states. Can you clarify if there's any actual issue here in the code you've shared? You could always call `setBio(null);` at the same time that `setPerson(....)` is called and then they are updated in the same render cycle.

Comment: I think this example is not full, because we don't now where `setPerson` is called

Answer (score 2):

```js
export default function Page() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState('Alice');
  const [bio, setBio] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    setIsLoading(true)
    fetchBio(person)
      .then(result => {
        if (!ignore) {
          setBio(result);
        }
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
        setIsLoading(false)
      });
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [person]);
  
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>`Profile of ${person}`</h1>
      {isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <>render(bio)</>}
    </>
  )
 }
```

Looks like you need a variable to control the status of getting data. I'm using `isLoading` for example. With it, you can decide what to show when waiting for the new bio, here is the div with loading... text

Answer (score 0):

If you use two separate state that are updated independently, then yes, there can be occasional times when the two are not in "agreement", e.g. the current `bio` state may not be that of the current `person` state.

Using a `useEffect` hook like this might be considered a bit of an anti-pattern though. If the intent is for the `person` and `bio` state to always be updated together then do the `bio` fetch at the same time that `person` will be updated, and enqueue the state updates to both when the UI has both new datas.

Basic Example:

```js
export default function Page() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState('Alice');
  const [bio, setBio] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async (person) => {
    const bio = await fetchBio(person);
    setPerson(person);
    setBio(bio);
  };

  ...

  <button type="button" onClick={() => fetchData("Bob")>
    Get Bob's data
  </button>

}
```

The above is the basic gist, but you should "fancy it up" with loading state/indicators, cancelling in-flight network requests (*Using "isLoaded" flags in hooks became a bit of a React anti-pattern over the past couple years*) if `Page` unmounts, etc in your actual code if that is something of a concern.